# Chance for two numbers to be same if first k digits matches

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two people pick two numbers (same number of digits say n). What is the chance that the number will be same number if their first k digits matches.

Answer (score 0):

If they both pick all the digits randomly and independently from each other, then the probability in the question is the same as the probability that the pick the remaining $n-k$ digits the same. This is $0.1^{n-k}$ since whatever $n-k$ remaining digits the first person chose, the second person will have that given probability of choosing the same digits.

Answer (score 0):

We have two numbers with $n$ digits having first $k$ digits same. In order that the numbers are same, the remaining $n-k$ digits must be same as well.

Now the number of ways of choosing the remaining $n-k$ digits of the first number are $10^{n-k}$. The two numbers are only equal when the remaining $n-k$ digits are same for second number as well. Thus there are $10^{n-k}$ cases where the two numbers are same given that first $k$ digits are same.

Now the total cases can be $10^{2(n-k)}$, since each of the two numbers have $10^{n-k}$ ways to choose remaining digits.

$\therefore P(\text{Two numbers are same})=\dfrac{10^{n-k}}{10^{2(n-k)}}=\dfrac{1}{10^{n-k}}$